# Can I book an adult ticket for a child?

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I was trying to book airplane tickets for my whole family, two adults, two children aged 8 and 3 on the website of the carrier. I can go though the entire booking process but when I click 'pay' I get the error message 'no infant tickets available for this flight'. I called the customer service and they claimed it should work.

My guess is that there is some bug in the booking software that treats children as infants (defined as 0 to 2 years old). The number of infant tickets can indeed be limited but a 3-year-old gets their own regular seat like an adult so I don't think any restrictions apply here.

The price difference between child and adult is neglible (10 euros because one small item out of a whole list of fees disappears) so I thought I could just try to book 4 adult tickets. Now my question is whether I could run into any problems if I have an adult ticket for someone born in 2019?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can book an adult ticket for a child.

These days airlines rarely offer different pricing for adults, youths, seniors, and children -- with the exception being INFS ("infant without a seat") tickets. The adult price is usually all that is on offer for anyone who needs a seat.